# Create multiple jobs in a forEach loop with Kue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, kue

I'm trying to create mutliple jobs in a `forEach` loop with `kue`, in my `forEach` I return a new Promise for each created job. Each job has the same key but a different email address in `data`. However, `kue` creates all the jobs with the last e-mail address in the list. I can't seem to figure out how to prevent this issue. Here is some code:

```
const emails = ['abc@test.com', 'def@test.com', 'efg@test.com'];

emails.forEach(email => {
    const extendedData = _.assign(data, { email });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        queue
          .create('notifyUsers', extendedData)
          .removeOnComplete(true)
          .save((err) => {
            if (err !== null) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve();
          });
    });
});
```

3 queues are created for `'efg@test.com'`. How can I get it to create a queue for each e-mail?

Thanks.

Comment: `const extendedData = _.assign(data, { email });` might be the issue. It looks like you are mutating `data` in each iteration. You probably want to create a copy of the object instead: `const extendedData = _.assign({}, data, { email });` (if that works).

Comment: I totally missed that part, thanks for pointing it out. It works fine now :)